# Convert long date to numbered date with FormatTime

Tags: autohotkey

I would like to convert long date to numbered format. I think there is a way of using FormatTime but it's not clear the syntax.

So take this `Sep 28, 2020` and convert to `9/28/2020`

```
; (I know this below doesn't work)
Raw_StartDateTime := "Sep 28, 2020, 1:00 PM"
Formattime, StartTime, % Raw_StartDateTime, M/d/yyyy HH:mm
msgbox % "Formatted Start Time: " StartTime
```

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage [this function](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/18760-date-parser-convert-any-date-format-to-yyyymmddhh24miss/) to first convert to AHK accepted format for using FormatTime (which is of the format YYYYMMDDHH24MISS). Then use the FormatTime function to further format it into desired format.

```
Raw_StartDateTime := "Sep 28, 2020, 1:00 PM"
StartDate := DateParse(Raw_StartDateTime)
Formattime, StartTime, % StartDate, M/d/yyyy HH:mm
msgbox % "Formatted Start Time: " StartTime
```